# Are there other ways to skin a mesh without Armature Deform with Automatic Weights?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

Because, I choose that option and it says "Failed to find solution for one or more bones". I, of course, put the rig inside the mesh. There is symmetry in my rig and they are appropriately named with bone.l or bone.r.[image: Problem with Skinning]. I tried several things.

I would be happy to provide any more details and thank you for any help you might provide.

Comment: Check out attached link.  I think you should find every possible reason for that failure in one or another of the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

You could parent the object to the armature with empty weights and then do the weights yourself. You might have better luck starting with a basic rig that is already linked into a shape and then match it up within your object and then try pairing it with automatic weights you might have better luck. Normally, it works, but there is always autorig pro, it has a smarter automatic weight painting system, you would probably like it.

Comment: You will find basic rig in the add drop down menu under armature and then parent with empty groups is in the parent section under the object drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks, man. I'm going to try that right now.